# Change UISegmentedControl.selectedIndex value depending on which UICollectionViewCell is currently shown

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, indexpath, segmentedcontrol

how can I change the UISegmentedControl.selectedIndex value depending on which UICollectionViewCell is currently shown?
My collectionView has the **isPagingEnabled set to true**, and I can easily select a different item depending on the selected index of my UISegmentedControl, but how can I do the opposite?

*Is there a function that gets called called every time the user changes page of the collectionView that also gives the indexPath of the currently shown item?*

Accessing the visibleCells array doesn't seem to be any useful.
A function like

```
func collectionViewDidPage(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, _ fromIndexPath: IndexPath, _ toIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let tag = myCollectionView.cellForItem(at: toIndexPath).tag
    self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = tag
}
```

where **fromIndexPath** and **toIndexPath** are the indexPaths of the two cells (the one from which I started scrolling and the one I'm going to end scrolling) could work.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you try `collectionView(_:didUpdateFocusIn:with:)` delegate method?

Comment: @AnushaKottiyal how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code seems to be working pretty fine:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageNumber = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = Int(pageNumber)
}
```